# About MaximumAttachmentSize?

Tags: windows-registry

Im trying to increase the attachment size of emails and i find out it could be done from modifying the registry by accesing the sub key from there and change the value to 0 to have no limits for the attachments.

I heard its also it could be armful to modify the registry sometimes and you have to know how to make registry backups and restoring, which is i know how to do both.

My question is would it still be harmful if i changed only that subkey or it is okay to do it? Is there anything else i need to know about?

Comment: "that subkey " which one is that specifically?

Comment: HKEY_CURRENT_USER>software>Microsoft>Office>15.0>outlook>Preferences

I want to add DWORD 32bit value
Then name it by MaximumAttachmentSize
Specify the value of 0 for no limits

Comment: What mail client (and version) are you using?  What email - IMAP or exchange?  Assuming it is Outlook note changing `MaximimAttachmentSize` to 0 will only affect warnings about size - it will not let you send unlimited size attachments.  See [here](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/increase-maximum-attachment-size-limit)

Comment: We really need more information here. Attachment size of emails from what program? Your question doesn't say, and many different clients could use the Windows registry.

Comment: I'm using outlook i think the limits is 20MB for the attachments